# Map of France with Regions and departments - MAPEL - by NEVELDO

Tags: vector, regions, mapael

I want to use the script of Neveldo for Mapael in order to insert the regions in the map of France as well as the departments.

I can not nest the codes for the different JS files in each region provided in a single file by Neveldo: https://github.com/neveldo/mapael-maps/tree/master/france.

So I wish to keep the current interactivity of this map by including the regions of NEVELDO. http://cnecj.org/cnejc/annuaire/#cours-appel

The site VincentBroute.fr/Mapael does not give documentation and on the Github either.

Can you help me understand the architecture of this code and possibly give me a solution to nest: map of France, regions and departments?

thank you

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you are trying to do, so I will try my best to answer broadly.

In Mapael, a map is composed of *areas*. These areas are defined in the map file.

For instance, the map [france_departments](https://github.com/neveldo/jQuery-Mapael/blob/master/js/maps/france_departments.js) defines 95 areas, which corresponds to all (Metropolitan) France departments.

However, in the map [france_regions_2016](https://github.com/neveldo/mapael-maps/blob/master/france/france_regions_2016.js), it defines 12 areas which corresponds to all (Metropolitan) regions of France

**This means that a map in Mapael cannot have the regions *and* its departments, because they would overlap and hide each other.** This is because they are showing the same thing but with different level of details.

So, if you want to have the departments (in order to show details about it) as well as being able to recognize each regions, the best approach would be to use the map which has the most level of details you need (i.e. the one with departments) and group departments by regions by visually filling them with different colors (e.g. green for Normandie, yellow for Bretagne, and so on...).

Comment: Thanks for your reply, and so sorry to not add have answer you. I had abandoned my idea because that would be too long to rework all of the code in Mapael.